# UploadWriteFailed(reason=WriteError('disallowed_name', None)

Tags: python, dropbox

I'm trying to upload a whole folder to dropbox but only the files get uploaded. Should I create a folder programatically or can I solve the folder-uploading so simple? Thanks

```
   import os
   import dropbox

   access_token = '***********************'

   dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(access_token)

   dropbox_destination = '/live'
   local_directory = 'C:/Users/xoxo/Desktop/man'

   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(local_directory):

       for filename in files:
           local_path = root + '/' + filename
           print("local_path", local_path)
           relative_path = os.path.relpath(local_path, local_directory)
           dropbox_path = dropbox_destination + '/' + relative_path

           # upload the file
           with open(local_path, 'rb') as f:
               dbx.files_upload(f.read(), dropbox_path)
```

error:

```
dropbox.exceptions.ApiError: ApiError('xxf84e5axxf86', UploadError('path', UploadWriteFailed(reason=WriteError('disallowed_name', None), upload_session_id='xxxxxxxxxxx')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/UploadWriteFailed-reason-WriteError-disallowed-name-None/td-p/245765 ]

There are a few things to note here:

- In your sample, you're only iterating over `files`, so you won't get `dirs` uploaded/created.
- The [/2/files/upload](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload) endpoint only accepts file uploads, not folders. If you want to create folders, use [/2/files/create_folder_v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-create_folder_v2). You don't need to explicitly create folders for any parent folders in the `path` for files you upload via [/2/files/upload](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload) though. Those will be automatically created with the upload.
- Per the [/2/files/upload documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload), `disallowed_name` means:

> Dropbox will not save the file or folder because of its name.

So, it's likely you're getting this error because you're trying to upload an ignored filed, e.g., `".DS_STORE"`. You can find more information on those in [this help article under "Ignored files"](https://www.dropbox.com/help/syncing-uploads/files-not-syncing).

Comment: thanks for your help. 2 things that are still not clear: 1, so I can't upload a folder containing files with only 1 command? 2, I have this code and no folder get created in dropbox: import dropbox; at="***"; dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(at); dbx.create_folder_v2('alma')
Why can that be? Thanks

Comment: 1. You can make a single call to upload a file, e.g., to "/folder/file.ext", and "/folder" will automatically be created if it doesn't already exist. 2. Calling `create_folder_v2` should create a folder, but check if you're getting any exception, or check what the result is. For example, the page should be like `'/alma'`, not `'alma'`.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Dropbox' object has no attribute 'create_folder_v2' The current version of dropbox is 8.2.0

Comment: Oh, in the Python SDK the full method name is [`files_create_folder_v2`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_create_folder_v2).

Comment: Thanks very much, Greg. You are really helpful as always.